# How to return a List of Person instead of String using Java8?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

Right now, I am returning a String with the reversed names.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();

    personList.add(new Person("Jamie", 23, Gender.MALE));
    personList.add(new Person("Tom", 33, Gender.MALE));
    personList.add(new Person("Nancy", 30, Gender.FEMALE));
    personList.add(new Person("Michelle", 10, Gender.FEMALE));

    System.out.println(reverseWordInList(personList));
}

public static String reverseWords(String sentence) {
    return PATTERN.splitAsStream(sentence)
            .map(s -> new StringBuilder(s).reverse())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

But, I want the reversed values in a new `List<String>` how can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use the method `reverseWords` in the `Stream<Person>` and get the `List<String>` with reversed names.

```
List<String> names = personList.stream()
                               .map(person -> reverseWords(person.getName())) 
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Therefore, the method `reverseWordInList` might look like:

- `Person` specific:

  ```
  reverseWordInList(personList);
  ...

  static List<String> reverseWordInList(List<Person> personList) {
      return personList.stream()
                       .map(person -> reverseWords(person.getName()))
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
  ```
- Generic

  ```
  reverseWordInList(personList, Person::getName);
  ...

  static <T> List<String> reverseWordInList(List<T> list, Function<T, String> getter) {
      return list.stream()
                 .map(t -> reverseWords(getter.apply(t)))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
  ```

Note that the methods return a *new* list and doesn't modify the original one.